# Why WPF designer won't load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, designer

I shut down my VS2015 last night. Start it today and my WPF form refuses to load in the designer:

[image: Error]

I have tried cleaning, restarting VS2015 and restarting the computer.

What can I do? :(

Update: I installed latest update and was still having issues.

Then I killed the designer and ended up seeing an exception in the designer. It had an option to switch off using the code or something. So I unticked it. Then it opened! Then I traced my program startup and found an infinite loop! The way I had written it meant that on a Monday the loop woudl stop correctly - and it was Monday yesterday! Today being Tuesday caused my loop to hang.

So I have fixed the code. But this means that the designer no longer shows dynamic content and I do not know how to switch that back on.

Comment: Try to open project in Blend for Visual Studio first, it that fails too - reinstall Visual Studio (I know that is a blunt solution but might help). Also might download latest update on Windows - I`ve have several times unusual issues with the VS when Windows required updates ...

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us if it happens only in specific xaml? And if this is so, what do you have inside (show code)? Maybe try removing parts of the xaml to see if it works.

Comment: @Jai Specific XAML. It is a lengthy XAMl file that I have been working on a few days. Was fine yesterday. So nothing has changed sicne then. I am trying to update VS2015. Then try again.

Comment: Try removing everything except the root element. Then gradually add things in.

Comment: Does the project build successfully?

Comment: @michauzo It has no errors. But ... to build I have to right click the project on the left and it won't run anymore. All I know is it was hunky dory last night. :( I am running the VS2015 update. Take it from there.

Comment: Between design and XAML there is a button named 'Disable project code'. Check it and try load again. If this problem disappears, it's codebehind fault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

find xaml designer process `XDesProc.exe` and kill it using task manager. Reopen file and everything should be ok. If not - install updates or reinstall visual studio.

Comment: Thanks. I am installing latest update. See how this goes.

Comment: I reinstalled. But I am going to update teh question with my findings.

Comment: `taskkill /f /IM XDesProc.exe`